# WindowAdapter In Inner Class

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm working on a Java school assignment, thought I had it all finished, but then went over the requirements one more time and realized I overlooked a specific requirement and now I need to rewrite a section of code, but I don't understand what the requirements are asking me for.

I need something to happen when the GUI window closes, currently I have it written as a simple method and it works fine, but the assignment is saying "**the handler should be an object of an inner class that extends the WindowAdapter class.**" I've got a basic understanding of inner classes and extending, but this saying it needs to be an object? I'm confused.

Currently I just have this as a part of the GUI class, and it works fine, I know the requirements are asking for something different but I don't know how to do it:

```
addWindowListener (new WindowAdapter()
{
    public void windowCloses(WindowEvent e)
    {
           try
           {
                //Code logic
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
             //Error print
             e.getWindow().dispose();
           }
    }
```

As I said, everyone works fine now, but I don't think this is what is required. I would ask my professor but I don't think he'll get back to me in time for the deadline.

How do I go about rewriting this code to meet the requirements?'

Thanks!

edit: Adding to this based on the information I've received so far (thanks!)

```
class innerClass extends WindowAdapter {

      public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){

           //Same logic as above
      }
}
```

I think I figured it out. So now I create an instance of this class and add the windowListener to that?

Comment: Have a quick look at my answer below, and read basic examples about **inner classes** and I'm sure you'll have no problem to tweak your code accordingly. Don't hesitate to ask for some precision if you need!

Comment: And don't forget to upvote @ccjmne's answer, and perhaps accept it if it answers your question. It's a good one.

Comment: Wow, thanks @HovercraftFullOfEels, that means a lot to me coming from you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like you got everything right!

Now what I assume your teacher means is: *the handler should be an **instance** (not "object") of an inner class that extends the `WindowAdapter` class*.

By doing the following:

```
new WindowAdapter() {

    // Use annotations, it's useful :)
    @Override
    public void windowCloses(WindowEvent e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

... you're actually creating a new **anonymous** class that `extends WindowAdapter`. In this new definition, you **override** the `WindowAdapter#windowCloses` method, then you **instantiate** it in a **new object** that you pass as an argument to `addWindowListener`.

Apparently, your teacher expects you to actually define an **inner class** and create a new instance of it. I don't wanna just give you the code for this but you're god damn close, you'll figure it out in an instant!

Comment: With the code written this way, where do I put the windowListener?

Comment: I think I'm understanding better, it's not completely clear but I edited the original to add what I've done. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I just read your updated question! It's perfect (except that the convention is to have all class names start with an uppercase), you got it! Now you can use `addWindowListener(new InnerClass())` :)

Comment: Thanks! The lowercase letter was just me getting in a hurry, I follow the traditional conventions as much as I can.

Answer (score 0):

To what I can understand, this should help :

```
 addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowCloses(WindowEvent e) {
        try{
            int confirmed = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, 
            "This is my handler. Shall I Exit?", "Exit Message Box, JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (confirmed == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {                                        
              dispose();
            }
         }
      catch(Exception ex){
          //Error print
        e.getWindow.dispose()
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it appears you may have misunderstood. I didn't need help writing the code logic, I left it out because it all works fine. I was actually asking for a way to rewrite the code as an inner class, but I'm pretty confused about the whole thing.